# $(A+B)x^2- Bx= 2x$ Polynomial - Identities

Tags: polynomials

I have a question about these polynomial identities:

$$(A+B)x^2 - Bx = 2x$$

$$A+B=0$$

$$-B =2$$

$$B =-2$$

$$A =-B$$

$$A =2$$

---

**Questions:**

Why is it $A=-B$?

Also, why can the minus sign switch to the other side?

$-B=2$

then

$B=-2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the first bit. You can write your equation as:
$$\color{red}{(A+B)x^2}\color{green}{-Bx}=\color{red}{0x^2}+\color{green}{2x}$$
Comparing coefficients of the $x^2$ and $x$ terms gives:
$$(A+B)x^2=0x^2 \iff A+B=0$$
$$-Bx=2x \iff -B=2$$

---

**Your first question:**
$$A+B=0$$
Subtract both sides of the equation by $B$. Then:
$$A+B\color{red}{-B}=\color{red}{-B} \iff A=-B$$

---

**Your second question:**
$$-B=2$$
Multiply both sides of the equation by $-1$:
$$-B\color{red}{\times -1}=2\color{red}{\times -1} \iff B=-2$$